# Highcharts - Line Graph Marker Rendering Unreliable?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to do a Highcharts line graph with markers at each data point (in addition to the line connecting the data points). Seems easy enough (and Highcharts does provide working examples), but I'm finding that three of my six series' plots just aren't including the markers. Here's my markup/code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {text: 'Things and Stuff',x: -18} ,
        xAxis: {
            title: {text: 'Whatsits'},
            plotLines: [{value: 0,width: 1,color: '#808080'}]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: { text: 'Widgets'},
            plotLines: [{value: 0,width: 1,color: '#808080'}]
        },
        legend: {layout: 'vertical',align: 'right',verticalAlign: 'middle',borderWidth: 0},
        series:[        
         {"name":"One - FAIL","data":[{"x":2800,"y":447420},{"x":3185,"y":461433},{"x":3190,"y":465400},{"x":3253,"y":473330}],"marker":{"radius":8}},        
         {"name":"Two - FAIL","data":[{"x":2417,"y":314903},{"x":2420,"y":332900},{"x":2463,"y":312903},{"x":2602,"y":333900},{"x":2675,"y":329930},{"x":2796,"y":350900},{"x":2841,"y":334900},{"x":2857,"y":352900}],"marker":{"radius":8}},        
         {"name":"Three - PASS","data":[{"x":3022,"y":454900},{"x":3084,"y":469900},{"x":3257,"y":474900},{"x":3340,"y":484900}],"marker":{"radius":8}},                
         {"name":"Four - PASS","data":[{"x":3255,"y":458311},{"x":3417,"y":467290},{"x":3604,"y":474000},{"x":3768,"y":474490}],"marker":{"radius":8}},        
         {"name":"Five - PASS","data":[{"x":2672,"y":414990},{"x":3043,"y":441990},{"x":3146,"y":450990},{"x":3253,"y":436990},{"x":3667,"y":443990},{"x":4217,"y":460990}],"marker":{"radius":8}},        
         {"name":"Six - FAIL","data":[{"x":3022,"y":447900},{"x":3084,"y":457900},{"x":3254,"y":514900},{"x":3257,"y":462900},{"x":3340,"y":472900},{"x":3469,"y":539900},{"x":3584,"y":539900},{"x":3586,"y":524900},{"x":3916,"y":539900}],"marker":{"radius":8}},
        ],
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The series with "FAIL" in their names just don't end up having markers, in my observation. This holds true in IE and Chrome. In Chrome, if you zoom *way* out, I think the markers do start (barely) showing up.

Interestingly, the markers *do* show up if you hover over where they should be, i.e. if you bring up to data point's tooltip.

Any idea what's going on? To me, this seems inexplicable (i.e. a bug in the library), but I'm pretty new to Highcharts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Highcharts is "failing" at understanding your data. For the markers to appear in every series you need to force them to be enabled by adding:

```
plotOptions: {
    line : {
        marker : {
            enabled : true,
        }
    }
}
```

To your chart configuration.

As the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker.enabled) says:

> enabled : Boolean
>
> Enable or disable the point marker. If null, the markers are hidden when the data is dense, and shown for more widespread data points. Defaults to null.

For Highcharts your data is dense, thats why it's hiding the markers in some series.